# Excel VBA Linking tickboxes to correct cells after copying

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns of Tickboxes. Columns E7:E30 and F7:F30
I also have an insert a new line which copies the cells above and shifts everything down by one row between a range of cells

Code for that here:

```
Private Sub InsertNewBill_Click()
Range("A30:AC30").Select
Range("AC30").Activate
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

The issue i have is that the tickboxes in Column E is linked to its respective neighbour in cell A and F is linked to B. Please see the attached image for an idea of the layout.

[image: Layout for the affected cells]

When using the above code. It copies everything as expected. However it binds the tick boxes together. I need to get the newly inserted tickboxes to bind to their relative A and B cells and have no idea how to do this. Would anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small piece of code that will loop through your checkboxes and links the cells 4 to its left:

```
Sub LINK()
Dim s As Shape

For Each s In Worksheets("Blad1").Shapes
    If s.Type = 8 then
        s.ControlFormat.LinkedCell = s.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -4).Address
    End if
Next s

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

This is basically the same answer as @Davesexcel his answer. Instead of ActiveX I assumed you used form elements.... Also a check if shape type is checkbox (type = 8).

Comment: Thank you for all your time on this. Its really apprecaited. I have altered the code slightly and posted my code below to get an understanding of what i have now done

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the checkboxes and set the linked cells, it looks like in the picture you are using activex checkboxes, as the command button as well is an activex control.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim objCkBox As Object
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each objCkBox In .OLEObjects
            If TypeName(objCkBox.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
                With objCkBox.TopLeftCell
                    r = .Row
                    c = .Column
                End With
                objCkBox.LinkedCell = Cells(r, c - 4).Address
            End If
        Next objCkBox
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work, although only with ActiveX which i abandoned and led to my adaptation below! I appreciate your time on this. It really helped my understand whats going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solved this now using an Offset address function
The following code deletes the tickboxes within a range and re-populates the tickboxes and links with an offset cell. Will be used to increment with every click of a different button

Code with annotations below:

```
Private Sub DeleteTickBoxes_Click()
'Variables
Dim c As CheckBox
Dim CellRange As range
Dim cel As range
Set CellRange = ActiveSheet.range("E7:F30")

'Delete Checkboxes within the specified range above on the ActiveSheet Only
For Each c In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If Not Intersect(c.TopLeftCell, CellRange) Is Nothing Then
    c.Delete
End If

Next

'Insert New Checkboxes and Assign to a specified link cell using the offset
For Each cel In CellRange
    Set c = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cel.Left, cel.Top, 30, 6) 'you can adjust left, top, height, width to your needs
    With c
        'Clears the textbox so it has no text
        .Caption = ""

        'Offset works by offsetting (Row offset, Column Offset) and accepts positive for down/right and negative for left/up,
        'keep in not that the linked cells will automatically populate with true/false
        .LinkedCell = cel.Offset(0, -4).Address

    End With

Next
Call CentreCheckbox_Click()
End Sub
```